# How to changing size of dynamically allocated matrix?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, size

I have an C exercice at school. I had to make a dynamically allocated matrix filled with random number and which have a size choosing by user. Then, the program ask to the user to redefine a bigger size, and the new matrix have to keep old values and fill new values with random.

The program is blocking when I'm trying to redefine the size of the matrix. I'm receiving a segmentation fault as of line 73. I dont understand why :|

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stddef.h>

int nbRand() {
    static int first = 0;

    if(first == 0) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        first = 1;
    }

    return rand()%10;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
    int **matrice, **matrice2; // Tableau
    int i, j; // Compteur
    int longueur1, largeur1, longueur2, largeur2; // Taille dynamique tableau
    size_t n;

    printf("Saisissez la taille du tableau.\n");
    printf("Longueur : ");
    scanf("%d", &longueur1);
    printf("Largeur : ");
    scanf("%d", &largeur1);

    matrice = (int**) malloc(longueur1*sizeof(int*));

    for(i = 0; i < longueur1; i++) {
        matrice[i] = (int*) malloc(largeur1*sizeof(int));
    }

    /* Autre manière
    matrice = (int*) malloc(longueur1*largeur1*sizeof(int));
    */

    for(i = 0; i < longueur1; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < largeur1; j++) {
            matrice[i][j] = nbRand();
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < longueur1; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < largeur1; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrice[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Agrandir la matrice
    printf("NOUVELLE TAILLE\n");

    do {    
        printf("Longueur : ");
        scanf("%d", &longueur2);
    } while(longueur2 < longueur1);

    do {    
        printf("Largeur : ");
        scanf("%d", &largeur2);
    } while(largeur2 < largeur1);

    matrice2 = (int**) realloc(matrice, longueur2*sizeof(int*));

    for(i = 0; i < longueur2; i++) {
        matrice2[i] = (int*) realloc(matrice[i], largeur2*sizeof(int));
    }

    matrice=matrice2;

    for(i = 0; i < longueur2; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < largeur2; j++) {
            matrice[i][j] = nbRand();
            printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, j, matrice[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("test\n");
    for(i = 0; i < longueur2; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < largeur2; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrice[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

EDITED :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stddef.h>

int nbRand() {
    static int first = 0;

    if(first == 0) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        first = 1;
    }

    return rand()%10;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
    int** matrice;
    int** tmp; // Tableau
    int i, j; // Compteur
    int longueur1, largeur1, longueur2, largeur2; // Taille dynamique tableau
    size_t n;

    printf("Saisissez la taille du tableau.\n");
    printf("Longueur : ");
    scanf("%d", &longueur1);
    printf("Largeur : ");
    scanf("%d", &largeur1);

    matrice = (int**) malloc(longueur1*sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i < longueur1; i++) {
        *(matrice+i) = (int*) malloc(largeur1*sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i = 0; i < longueur1; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < largeur1; j++) {
            matrice[i][j] = nbRand();
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < longueur1; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < largeur1; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrice[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Agrandir la matrice
    printf("NOUVELLE TAILLE\n");

    do {    
        printf("Longueur : ");
        scanf("%d", &longueur2);
    } while(longueur2 < longueur1);

    do {    
        printf("Largeur : ");
        scanf("%d", &largeur2);
    } while(largeur2 < largeur1);

    tmp = (int**) realloc(matrice, longueur2*sizeof(int*));

    for(i = 0; i < longueur2; i++) {
        *(tmp + i) = (int*) realloc(*(tmp+i), largeur2*sizeof(int));
    }

    matrice=tmp;

    for(i = longueur1; i < longueur2; i++) {
        for(j = largeur2; j < largeur2; j++) {
            matrice[i][j] = nbRand();
            // printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, j, matrice[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("test\n");
    for(i = 0; i < longueur2; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < largeur2; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrice[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should google `realloc`.

Comment: Yeah but I don't understand where I am wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

```
matrice2 = (int**) realloc(matrice, longueur2*sizeof(int*));
for(i = 0; i < longueur2; i++) {
    matrice2[i] = (int*) realloc(matrice[i], largeur2*sizeof(int));
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
                                     |
                                      -> You are accessing old pointer here. 
}
```

is wrong, it should be

```
matrice2 = (int**) realloc(matrice, longueur2*sizeof(int*));
for(i = 0; i < longueur2; i++) {
    matrice2[i] =  realloc(matrice2[i], largeur2*sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Curious that code use the unnecessary cast `(int**)` in one place yet is tidy with `matrice2[i] =  realloc(...`

Comment: Thanks for answers... I tried that, but, I'm receiving a SIGTRAP error in GDB and here is the result : https://prnt.sc/q5okt3 of the program when I changed the size.

Comment: I added my code edited with my modifications in the first message.